# Grails Facebook-Graph Plugin Oauth2

Tags: facebook, grails, facebook-graph-api

We have been using the Grails Facebook-graph plugin for a while now - it has been working perfectly until earlier this month when FB apparently turned off their old authentication scheme, and indirectly forced everybody to use oauth2 instead.

This post from FB https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/ describes the changes, and the issue in the Grails plugin seems to be that it does not comply with the new standard.

The main issue appears to be in the way the active user data is being maintained in the plugin. This is currently based on the FB provided cookie "fbs", which contains all the necessary session data related to the active user. Unfortunately, this is no longer provided by FB (apparently replaced by a "fbsr" cookie instead).

I have searched the FB documentation, and in various forums for details on how to upgrade the plugin, but unfortunately without luck.

Can anyone help with a hint or two on what steps should be performed in order to get the plugin updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I think the updated version of the plugin (0.14) has been pushed the public repository.  You should try grabbing that one first before reading the rest of my answer.

It looks like the plugin maintainer, Jesus Lanchas, made some updates over the last few days to enable oauth2 support.  It has not been pushed to the plugin repository yet, but I was able to get it working with my project.  Here's what I did:

```
#Install a local copy of the plugin WITHIN my project
mkdir plugins-local
cd plugins-local
git clone git://github.com/chechu/grails-facebook-graph.git
mv grails-facebook-graph facebook-graph
```

Update BuildConfig.groovy and tell grails where to load the plugin from.  I put this line before grails.project.dependency.resolution

```
grails.plugin.location.'facebook-graph' = "plugins-local/facebook-graph"
```

Uninstall the existing facebook-graph plugin from my project

```
grails uninstall-plugin facebook graph
```

This is a *temporary* solution for me until the offical update hits the repo, but it allows me to make sure I'm using the same new code everywhere.

Comment: That looks really great. We will try out this during the coming week. Hope the new official version will be on the repo soon.

Comment: Have just downloaded and installed the new version. Seems to work perfectly. A big thank to Jesus Lanchas :-)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: we released our Facebook Grails SDK on GitHub :

https://github.com/benorama/facebook-grails-sdk.

Currently only tested on Grails 2.0…
Any feedback is welcome before we release it officially to Grails.org.

---

Indeed, it looks like Grails Facebook-graph plugin does not support **OAuth2 Facebook authentication** (which is required since October 1st 2011).

We have already ported the **official PHP SDK V3.1.1** to **ColdFusion 9** (https://github.com/affinitiz/facebook-cf-sdk).

Last month, we started to implement it as a plugin in **Grails 2.0**.
It is currently at an alpha stage so we have not released it yet, but it is working on our prototype.
To connect to the Facebook Graph API, it uses **RestFB** internally.

If you want to give it a try and give us some feedbacks, let me know, I'll sent it to you by email.

Comment: Hi Benoit, depending on how your plugin works it could be an option to upgrade to this instead. My original plan was to update the existing Grails FB-graph plugin and publish it back to repo, since it might help other Grails users as well. However, if your plugin will work with Grails 1.3.7 it might be a fine solution, as well. You are welcome to send me a link on email: development@turkino.net